# Flow type return type for async string

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm defining the return type of an async method as a **Promise < string >** using **flow-type**

If I add a try catch loop it doesn't work.

*Please click on the examples to see the code running on flow.org/try*

**Example 1 Doesn't work**  - [Code](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBDAzgTwHYDGYUAroQC4CWcexccAFAJQBcYACgE5wC2lWAUwA8Wcp0p4A5gD4wAb1RgwYnAqVLOA8iU60MCDJXJgA5FHonFYAL5gCGcgQAWYBgKZy7NLHBgCAdAKc3JxuTDao1qhAA)

```
async function foo(): Promise<string> {
  try {
    return await 'foo'
  } catch (e){ console.error(e) }
}
```

**Example 2  Works**  - [Code](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBDAzgTwHYDGYUAroQC4CWcexccAFAJQBcYACgE5wC2lWAUwA8Wcp0p4A5gD4wAb1RgwnAeRKdaGBBkrkwAcij19qAL6ogA)

```
async function foo(): Promise<string> {
  return await 'foo'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `catch` means that the function doesn't throw and thus returns `void`, so if you don't want that, then you'd need to re-throw the error, e.g.

```
try {
  return await 'foo'
} catch (e){ 
  console.error(e);
  throw e;
}
```

so that Flow knows you only want the string return value.

But then obviously the question is, why are you catching in the first place, instead of returning the string and catching in whatever called `foo`.

Alternatively if you actually want to report the error, but return a string, what should that string be? You can always do

```
try {
  return await 'foo'
} catch (e){ 
  console.error(e);
  return "";
}
```

Comment: You answers gives me a lot of clarity.
I add the catch because otherwise node outputs a warning regarding unhandled promises.

Answer (score 4):

*"I guess that posting the question helped me figure it out"*

**Works with Try/Catch**  [Code](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBDAzgTwHYDGYUAroQC4CWcexccAFAJQBcYACgE5wC2lWAUwA8Wcp0p4A5mAA+YAG5xKAEwB8YAN6owYMTi06dnAeRKdaGBBkrkwAcij072sAF8wBDOQIALMAwEmDQ8aLDgYAQA6AU5uTgCmN1RXVCA)

```
async function foo(): Promise<string | void> {
  try{
    return await 'foo'
  } catch (e){ console.error(e) }
}
```

I added **`| void`** to the type.
The reason being is because the catch is actually returning an undefined value which equals to void.

But I still wonder about what's another way to simplify the type code